# Run a script (like postinstall) after npm installing a single package?

Tags: npm, snowpack

I'm starting to play around with Snowpack. It takes a different approach from Webpack by bundling individual packages right after they're installed.

The "issue" is, when I install a package I have to first run `npm install --save my-package` and then I have to manually pack it with `npx snowpack`. The [Snowpack docs](https://www.snowpack.dev/#run-after-every-install) mention that I can include a `prepare` script that would `snowpack` everything after running `npm install` but that doesn't apply to individual packages, just on a generic `npm install` of all dependencies in my `package.json`. As far as I can tell, this is the case for all npm hooks mentioned in the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

Is there any way I can automatically run a script whenever I install an individual package? The only way I can think of would be to overwrite the install script and add something to it. Are there any examples of this on GitHub or elsewhere?

**Update:** For clarification, I'd like to run `npx snowpack` every time I install a new package with `--save` but preferably not with `--save-dev` or without `--save`. This will never be different for any package. This will be specific to a certain repo/project, not global on my system.

It is not sufficient to run `snowpack` after simply running `npm install` as you would get by hooking into `postinstall` or `release`. Additionally, I want to make sure developers working on my project can use `npm install --save newdep` as they normally would and then `snowpack` will run. I do not want to require devs to use a custom *named* script.

Comment: @RobC Good thought, though I don't want to chain commands. I'll post on here when I have a script that works well for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With newer versions of Snowpack (>=2) you can run `snowpack dev` and it will watch your `npm_modules` folder for new modules to build.

Answer (score 14):

**Short answer:** Unfortunately, npm does not provide any built-in feature(s) to meet your requirement.

Lifecycle hooks/scripts such as [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) are invoked only when running the generic [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) command, and not when someone runs `npm install --save <pkg_name>` during the projects development phase.

---

**Workaround:** Consider customizing the logic of the [`npm install --save`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/install.html) compound command by essentially overriding the `npm` command at the shell level.

The following solution, albeit a Bash one, describes how this custom logic can be actualized for a specific project(s). However, this solution is dependent on the following conditions:

- Developers working on your project must have their the shell set to [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) when running the `npm install --save` compound command.
- Developers working on your project will need to customize their Bash [startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), namely `~/.bashrc` and possibly `~/.bash_profile`.
- The project directory, i.e. the project directory for which you want the custom logic to be effective, must contain a custom `.bashrc` file.

---

### Bash Solution:

The following three steps are necessary to configure your project, and operating system(s), so that when a developer runs `npm install --save <pkg_name>` (or variations of it) the `npx snowpack` command is subsequently invoked.

**Note:** Points two and three (below) are the tasks developers need to carry out (once) to customize their Bash startup files.

1. **The project specific `.bashrc` file:**

   Firstly create the following *"project specific"* `.bashrc` file in the root of your project directory, i.e. save it at the same level as where your projects `package.json` file resides:

   **`/some/path/to/my-project/.bashrc`**

   ```sh
   npm() {

     local name_badge="\x1b[37;40mpostinstall\x1b[0m"

     array_includes() {
       local word=$1
       shift
       for el in "$@"; do [[ "$el" == "$word" ]] && return 0; done
     }

     log_warn_message() {
       local cmd_name=$1 warn_badge warn_mssg
       warn_badge="\x1b[30;43mWARN!\x1b[0m"
       warn_mssg="${cmd_name} command not found. Cannot run npx snowpack."
       echo -e "\n${name_badge} ${warn_badge} ${warn_mssg}" >&2
     }

     log_run_message() {
       echo -e "\n${name_badge} Running pseudo postinstall hook."
     }


     if [[ $* == "install "* || $* == "i "* ]] && array_includes --save "$@"; then

       # 1. Run the given `npm install --save ...` command.
       command npm "$@"

       # 2. Check whether the `npx` command exists globally.
       command -v npx >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
         log_warn_message npx
         return 1
       }

       log_run_message

       # 3. Run the pseudo "postinstall" command.
       command npx snowpack

     else
       # Run all other `npm` commands as per normal.
       command npm "$@"
     fi
   }
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** For a better understanding of what this file does refer to the *"Explanation"* section below.</sub>
2. **The `~/.bashrc` file:**

   To make the custom logic, i.e. the `npm` function in the aforementioned `.bashrc` file, effective, it's necessary to configure Bash to read the aforementioned *"project specific"* `.bashrc` file. To configure this, add the following line of code to `~/.bashrc`:

   ```sh
   PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ "$bashrc" != "$PWD" && "$PWD" != "$HOME" && -e .bashrc ]]; then bashrc="$PWD"; . .bashrc; fi'
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** For a better understanding of what this line of code does refer to the *"Explanation"* section below.</sub>
3. **The `~/.bash_profile` file:**

   Typically your `~/.bash_profile` contains the following line of code to load the `~/.bashrc` file (or some variation of it):

   ```sh
   if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
   ```

   If this is not present, then it must be added to `~/.bash_profile`.

---

### Additional info.

**Setup/Configuration helpers:**

Consider your developers utilizing the following two commands to aid configuration of their Bash startup files, as per the aforementioned steps two and three.

1. For step two, run the following command:

   ```sh
   echo $'\n'"PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ \"\$bashrc\" != \"\$PWD\" && \"\$PWD\" != \"\$HOME\" && -e .bashrc ]]; then bashrc=\"\$PWD\"; . .bashrc; fi'" >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

   This will add the `PROMPT_COMMAND=...` line of code to the existing `~/.bashrc` file, or create a new one if it doesn't already exist:
2. For step three, run the following command to append the line of code necessary in the `~/.bash_profile` for loading the `~/.bashrc` file:

   ```sh
   echo $'\n'"if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi" >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```

**Is my shell configured to Bash?**

To check whether the shell is configured to Bash you can create a new session, i.e. create a new Terminal window and run:

```
echo $0
```

If it prints `-bash` then it's using Bash.

**How do I configured my shell to Bash?**

If `echo $0` doesn't print `-bash` then you'll need to change the shell. To change it to Bash run:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Note: You'll need to create a new session for this change to become effective.

---

### Explanation

1. **The project specific `.bashrc` file:**

   This `.bashrc` file contains a [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) named `npm`. The body of this function contains the logic necessary to override the default `npm install|i --save` command.

   - The conditions specified in the `if` statement, i.e, the part that reads;

     ```sh
     if [[ $* == "install "* || $* == "i "* ]] && array_includes --save "$@"; then
       ...
     fi
     ```

     essentially reads the `$*` [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) to check whether the argument(s) passed to the `npm` function begin with either; `install` , or it's shorthand equivalent `i` , and whether the `--save` option/argument has been passed too.

     To check for the existence of the `--save` argument we pass the `$@` special parameter to the `array_includes` function. We handle this argument differently because the position of the `--save` option may differ in the compound command. For instance, a user may install a package by running this;

     ```sh
     # Example showing `--save` option at the end
     npm install <pkg_name> --save
     ```

     or this (or some other variation):

     ```sh
     # Example showing `--save` option in the middle
     npm i --save <pkg_name>
     ```
   - When the conditions specified in the `if` statement are met, i.e. they're `true`, we perform the following tasks in its body:

     1. Run the given `npm install --save ...` command as-is via the line that reads:

        ```sh
        command npm "$@"
        ```
     2. Check whether the `npx` command exists globally via the part that reads:

        ```sh
        command -v npx >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
          log_warn_message npx
          return 1
        }
        ```

        If the `npx` command is not available (globally) we warn the user that the `npx snowpack` command cannot be run, and `return` from the function early with an exit status of `1`.

        <sub>**Note:** My logic in this check assumes that you'll be installing `npx` globally. However if you're installing `npm` locally within your project then you'll need to change this logic. Perhaps by checking whether `./node_modules/.bin/npx` exists instead. Or, you may be confident that `npx` command will always exists, therefore conclude that this check is unnecessary.</sub>
     3. If the `npx` command exists globally we then run the pseudo "postinstall" command, i.e.

        ```sh
        command npx snowpack
        ```
   - When the conditions specified in the `if` statement are NOT met, i.e. they're `false`, the user is essentially running any other npm command that is not `npm install --save <pkg_name>`. Therefore in the `else` branch we run the command as-is:

     ```sh
     command npm "$@"
     ```
2. **The ~/.bashrc file:**

   In section [5.2 Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) of the *"Bash Reference Manual"* the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable is described as follows:

   > **`PROMPT_COMMAND`**
   >
   > If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt (`$PS1`).

   So, this line of code (here it is again):

   ```sh
   PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ "$bashrc" != "$PWD" && "$PWD" != "$HOME" && -e .bashrc ]]; then bashrc="$PWD"; . .bashrc; fi'
   ```

   loads the "project specific" `.bashrc` (if one exists), which in turn overrides the `npm` command with the `npm` function. This is what essentially provides a mechanism for overriding the `npm install --save` compound command for a specific project(s).

   <sub>See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/915703/is-there-a-folder-specific-bashrc-or-bash-profile#answer-915761) by `@Cyrus` for further explanation.</sub>

Comment: So much time and energy went into this answer, but it's clearly too overkill. I'm not question the legitimacy of your answer, it will give the effect that the OP is after. Just think about the person who continues his project who is not involved. Also this is not cross-platform supportive, but it looks really like a nice proof of concept that anything is possible, once more.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best bet would be to create a new script that performs the desired action. Something along the following lines in your package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "snowpack-install" : "npm install --save && npx snowpack"
  }
}
```

## Correction

You can actually use the [postinstall option](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in package.json. The postinstall will run "AFTER the package is installed". This would look something like the following:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall" : "npx snowpack"
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe `postinstall` only runs after running the generic form of `npm install`, so that won't do what I'm looking for. Additionally, I'd like to avoid having to run any custom named scripts since this would make it harder for teammates to pickup the project and install dependencies. I will clarify in the question.

Comment: What about perhaps using NPM hooks? https://blog.npmjs.org/post/145260155635/introducing-hooks-get-notifications-of-npm

Comment: Seems like overkill to call an external http service in this case (did hooks ever make it out of beta?)