# npm postinstall script for every project at user level

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I would like to run a user-level script or command after any time that I run `npm install` on a project on my computer. A similar concept to `npm-postinstall` but configured on a global / user level. Is this possible?

*My use case:* on Mac OSX, Spotlight is using serious energy to index my `node_modules`, I would like to automatically add a `.metadata_never_index` file every time.

Open to `yarn` solutions as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a script (like postinstall) after npm installing a single package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934610/run-a-script-like-postinstall-after-npm-installing-a-single-package)