# How to make a script run when using NPM commands?

Tags: npm

Trying to bind a [script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker) called `license-checker` to `npm` commands following [these instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) I came up with this snippet in my `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "license-checker --json --out license-list.json",
    "poststart": "license-checker --json --out license-list.json"
  },
```

Doesn't work. Running the command manually does generate the `licence-list.json` file, but not when installing a package (`npm i package-name --save`). Why not?

Note: I'm trying to run this script when (1) installing a new package into the project, and also when (2) building the project for deployment. However there's nothing about `build` [in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts): can I use `start` or `poststart` for that as I tried to or if not, what can I use instead?

Comment: Regarding _"run this script when (1) installing a new package into the project"_ - unfortunately npm does provide a built-in feature to achieve this. If you're using _*nix_ then consider  overriding the `npm install <pkg-name> --save` command at the shell level, as explained in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934610/run-a-script-like-postinstall-after-npm-installing-a-single-package/60096171#60096171).

Answer (score 0):

As per the npm documentation (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), the `postinstall` script is invoked when the package is installed so the `postinstall` script will invoke when you call

```
npm install
```

It **won't be called** when you invoke

```
npm i package-name --save
```

Maybe you can do the check once the package is installed.

Edit: If the purpose of this is to check what is being added to package.json maybe doing a pre-commit check/hooks will be a better idea aka using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky

Comment: I want for Git hooks indeed, turns out Vue (my App is Vue-based) natively incorporates aversion of Husky

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [hook-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#hook-scripts).

From docs :

> If you want to run a specific script at a specific lifecycle event for
> ALL packages, then you can use a hook script.
>
> Place an executable file at `node_modules/.hooks/{eventname}`, and
> it’ll get run for all packages when they are going through that point
> in the package lifecycle for any packages installed in that root.
>
> Hook scripts are run exactly the same way as package.json scripts.
> That is, they are in a separate child process, with the env described
> above.

**Edit**

Example:

I tried this on Windows 10, Node 12.18.0 and NPM 6.14.4

1. I created a bat file at `node_modules/.hooks/` having content:

```
call node -e "console.log('Hello, I got executed from .hooks folder.')"
```

2. Then ran `npm i ng-bootstrap --save`

Hook script got executed. Check screenshot below.
[image]

**Note** : *As pointed by @RobC, This script will be executed for each of the transitive dependencies of the package being installed.*

Comment: This won't run the script when installing new individual packages, if I understand correctly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096171/871404) by @RobC

Comment: @drake035 No, it will run for installing individual packages also. I have edited my answer to show example which I tried. And the documentation clearly states `If you want to run a specific script at a specific lifecycle event for ALL packages, then you can use a hook script.`.

Comment: @Smile - I see that `ng-bootstrap` has nothing defined in the `dependencies` section of its [package.json](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/package.json), so presumably this is why your _postinstall_ script is invoked only once. However if you run; `npm i eslint --save` _(note: eslint does have packages listed in the `dependencies` section of its [package.json](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/package.json))_ then presumably your _postinstall_ script is invoked multiple times, i.e. it's invoked for each and every transitive dependency installed too.

Comment: Does that mean that you were incorrect when stating that it's not possible to bind a script to the installation of individual packages @RobC?

Comment: @drake035 - it depends on what you define as an "individual package". Let's say you install a single package, e.g. eslint by running `npm i eslint --save`. My understanding of your requirement is that when e.g. eslint (and all it's transitive dependencies) has installed you want your _postinstall_ script to run once on completion. However, as eslint has multiple transitive dependencies (as you can see [here](http://npm.anvaka.com/#!/view/2d/eslint)) your _postinstall_ script will be run multiple times, i.e. it will run after each and every single transitive dependency is installed. Try it!

Comment: @drake035 - In summary... as you can see [here](http://npm.anvaka.com/#!/view/2d/eslint) eslint (for example) has a total of 107 nodes, which is essentially a total of 107 x transitive dependencies which are required to be installed for eslint to work. So, when you run `npm i eslint --save` your _postinstall_ script (i.e. whatever executable is defined in `node_modules/.hooks/`) will be invoked 107 times throughout the installation of eslint, and _not_ invoked just once upon completion. Note: I use eslint as an example, however typically npm packages have multiple transitive dependencies.

Comment: @RobC That is indeed true, script will run for each of the transitive dependencies. Not sure but may be some solution to run the script only once can be found by using `process.env` variables.

Comment: @Smile - Yes, you can attempt to infer from the environment variables when the last pkg is installed in an effort to make the _postinstall_ hook logic run only once at the end. This [example postinstall](https://paste.ee/p/1o6mx) `.js` script demos this. However it has limitations, as noted in the _CAVEAT_ section at the bottom. Also, **1)** The script still has to be processed after each transitive dependency is installed, thus increasing install times. **2)** When someone runs just `npm install` the _postinstall_ hook logic still has to be processed. Personally, I'm not a fan of this method.

Comment: "I created a bat file at node_modules/.hooks/ having content:" What filename did you use? If I use the recommended "postinstall" (without extension), Windows doesn't know how to run the file, correct?

Comment: @Venryx Yes windows might recognize that file, you can simply edit with any text editor and let node run it

Answer (score 0):

I dont tryed but, you can use a build script there you can use your commands by the way you aimed. by using the && operator.
For example:

```
"build": "npm run compile && npm run theme:build && npm run webpack:admin",
```

In your case like that:

```
"postinstall": "license-checker --json --out license-list.json",
"poststart": "license-checker --json --out license-list.json"
"build": "npm run poststart && npm run postinstall && npm run newpocket -save",
```

this is not exactly what you wanted but a manner for making it.